# Wrong emojis displaying in TextView

Tags: android, textview, emoticons

I have an array of my own Emoticons (Emojis) in my app which are called from the API. What's happening is that when I get the images I only get the last emoticon used displayed in the `TextView`. No idea what I need to do to correct this. I've posted my code below on how I replace the code for emoji to the html equivalent and using an `ImageGetter` with Picasso to display them.

Here is what I'm typing[image: Compose message]

And here is what's displaying [image: display in TextView]

Here's the code in my `PostAdapter`

```
    if (posts.getPost().getMessage() != null) {
        message = posts.getPost().getMessage();
        emoMessage = message;
        emoMessage = emoMessage.replace("\n", "<br>");


        if (emoticons != null) {
            for (Emoticons emoticon : this.emoticons) {
                if (message.contains(emoticon.getEmoticon().getCode())) {
                    emoMessage = message.replaceAll(Constants.EMO_REGEX,
                            "<img width=“120px“ height=“120px” src=" + '"'
                                    + emoticon.getEmoticon().getUrl() + '"' + "/>");
                }

            }
        }
    }

holder.mPostTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(emoMessage.replace("\r\n", "<br/>"), new PicassoImageGetter(mContext.getResources(),
                    mPicasso, holder.mPostTextView);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I can also give more code if needed.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: In the example code you posted, the holder.mPostTextView.setText is outside of the for loop, is this by accident? Or else that might be your problem.

Comment: There's loads of other code up until that point. I'll put it in there to check

Comment: Yeah that didn't work